# Commutator of two PDO.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\partial_0=\partial_t$ and $g^{00}=1$. Consider the following quasilinear PDO:

\begin{align}
Lu=\sum_{j,k=0}^{n}g^{jk}(t,x)\partial_j\partial_ku+\sum_{j=0}^{n}b^j(t,x)\partial_ju+au
\end{align}

If $\beta$ is a multi-index with $|\beta|\le s$, I'm told that the commutator $[L,\partial_x^\beta]$ is a differential operator of order less that $|s|+1$ (Sogge, Nonlinear Wave, Page 23).

1. I believe this is true insofar as the space derivatives will commute with eachother, so the bracket annihilates the terms in the double sum consisting of solely space derivatives, leaving terms with only $\partial_x^\beta$ and $\partial_0$ in them. Is this the right idea?
2. Is there a convention in PDE that space and time derivatives don't commute with each other? If they don't commute, I'm unsure of why the commutator isn't just an operator of order $2$.

Answer (score 0):

A) The number of spatial partial derivatives vs the number of temporal derivatives plays a relatively small role in OP's question. The total order of spacetime derivatives in each differential monomials is more important. Yes, the partial derivatives (of any type) commute.

B) Let a differential operator (DO) be a polynomial in $\partial_0, \partial_1, \ldots,$ with coefficients consisting of smooth functions. It's an important fact that the commutator $[P,Q]$ of two DOs $P$ and $Q$ of order $p$ and $q$, respectively, will have order $\leq p+q-1$. (This agrees with Sogge's estimate because $L$ is of order 2.)

C) It is not true that $[\partial_x^\beta,L]$ always has order $\leq 2$. Counterexample in 1 spatial dimension: $$[\partial_x^\beta,L]=[\partial^2_x,x\partial^2_x]=[\partial^2_x,x]\partial^2_x=2\partial^3_x$$ is of third order.